# How to dismiss iOS camera Access popup?

Tags: ios

My app requests access to the iPhone/iPad camera. This results in the native iOS popup to appear, asking for user confirmation.

Is there a way in which I can dismiss this iOS popup (so before the user has made the OK / Don't Allow choice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For recent versions of iOS this popup automatically appears when you request write or read access for iOS Photo Library or use some of the `AVFoundation` framework components.

You can not dismiss it programmatically but you sure can create your own alert before showing the system one so you can have more control over what the user does.

It is the case in many 3rd party apps because when the user declines the access, it's not easy to ask them to go to settings and re-enable it from there. One of the easiest examples to implement would be [something like this](https://clevertap.com/blog/asking-for-ios-push-notification-permissions/).